# Magento 2: re-arrange checkout address fields

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout, address

I want to change the order of the billing address inputs in checkout, so that the postcode field will be ordered before the city field.

I've tried to set the orders in `/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml` in my extension:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="billingAddress" xsi:type="array">

                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="billing-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="street" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="city" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">3</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="region_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">4</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="country_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">5</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="lastname" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">6</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="firstname" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">7</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="company" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">8</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">9</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Unfortunately, nothing changes in checkout. Even after clearing cache and pub/static.

Comment: how did you resolve this issue?

Comment: I resolved the issue according to Aaron Allen's answer below (https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/161036/720)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make a plugin for the `process` method of `Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor` and then alter the `jsLayout` array. I got it to work using the code below:

```
class Reorder
{

    public function afterProcess($subject, $jsLayout)
    {
        foreach ($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                 ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'] as &$child)
        {
            if (isset($child['children']['form-fields'])) {
                $child['children']['form-fields']['children']['postcode'] = array_merge(
                    $child['children']['form-fields']['children']['postcode'],
                    ['sortOrder' => 75]
                );
            }
        }

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```